# mediaplayer use in kotlin. Simple xylophone

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin and android studio.
Was trying to create a xylophone app. Created several buttons with onClick listeners. Each one plays a different audio file note from my raw folder. Works fine but stops playing the notes after 10+ klicks on any button. I`m stuck on this for a while.

```
class music : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music)
    val cButton = findViewById(R.id.c_key) as Button
    val dButton = findViewById(R.id.d_key) as Button
    val eButton = findViewById(R.id.e_key) as Button
    val fButton = findViewById(R.id.f_key) as Button
    val gButton = findViewById(R.id.g_key) as Button
    val aButton = findViewById(R.id.a_key) as Button
    val bButton = findViewById(R.id.b_key) as Button

    cButton.setOnClickListener {
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.note1_c)
        mp.start()
    }
    dButton.setOnClickListener {
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.note2_d)
        mp.start()
    }
```

... continues for all buttons. ty

Comment: Thanks for help but it looks I shoul learn Java first because of the avilable tutorials avilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I suggest to use a single `MediaPlayer` object declared inside `onCreate()`:

```
var mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.note1_c)
```

then inside each listener:

```
if (mp.isPlaying) mp.stop()
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.note1_x)
mp.start()
```

Comment: It looks like I don`t have to use mediaPlayer but SoundPool. Found it on the android page but still have no idea how to implement it. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/SoundPool

Comment: Cant find any tutorials how to use it in kotlin.